# iOS - View is not open (navigation controller app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I do a application have a navigation controller, the application works fine but in one UIView I have a UITableView.

[image: Example of the application]

When push cell I need open new view. I tried this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
NextViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
[nextView release];
```

But the view does not open. I tried this too:

```
NextViewController *screen = [[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextView" bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
[screen release];
```

Now the view it's open, but not correctly positioned, is under top navigation bar and tab bar and a part in view is hidden.

How can I open the view correctly?

EDIT:

I put o ther UIButton in other UIView to open other secondary UIView and doesnt work. I'm completely confused.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redesign your view to display properly when presented as a modal view

Comment: I do not want to present it as modal. I do not understand why the right way does not work.

Comment: what is the value of self.navigationController?

Answer (score 0):

use this verify that ur nib file has the name NextViewController exactly

NextViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:NextViewController animated:YES];

[NextViewController release];

Comment: I was wrong when I wrote the post. I just edit. The program is set as you say and does not work.

Comment: delete the NextViewController nib then create and  give the new name for that nib.then replace that new name to extViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"urnewNamehere" bundle:nil];